# Changing domain name for website still refers to old domain name

Tags: 6

I have recently changed a domain name for a Drupal 6 website and am now experiencing weird behaviour. While I can view the front page of the website using the new domain name, any other pages or links I try to access refers to the old domain name. This is what you would see in the browser's url:

```
Home page:        mynewdomain.com
Interior page:    myolddomain.com/node
```

Shouldn't Drupal automatically know the new domain name? I have searched for a solution and can't find anything. What is causing this, and how do I fix it? This is really screwing up SEO rankings.

Comment: Check if there are domain-specific rules in your `.htaccess` file, that cause the visitor to be redirected to the old domain. Also, have a look in `settings.php` file and see if the full site URL has been defined there.

Comment: I checked the .htaccess file and the settings.php file as suggested and there is nothing in there that refers to the old domain name. Could the problem be that on the hosting provider's server that the directory that the site's files are contained in is called myolddomain.com?

Comment: Also check your html template file (or just view source) for `<base href="http://myolddomain.com/">`